# apply function changing abruptly python

Tags: python, dataframe, apply

i am trying to figure out the effect of apply on dataframe and expecting same change to be taken across each row. Unable to figure out the result of following program:

```
  import pandas as pd
  def fun(x):
      x[0]=x[0]*2
      return x

  df=pd.DataFrame({"a":[1,2,3], "b":[11,12,13], "c":[10,20,30]}) 
  df=df.apply(fun,axis=1) 
  df=df.apply(fun,axis=1) 
  print df
```

please help me understand this. Thanks in advance.

expecting row indexed 0: 4,11,10 
but getting row indexed 0 : 8,11,10
the value in x[0] for row 0 is abruptly changing in multiple of 4 in second "apply".

Comment: Applying twice `df.iloc[:,0] = df.iloc[:,0]*2` should do what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Notes
>
> In the current implementation apply calls func twice on the first
>   column/row to decide whether it can take a fast or slow code path.
>   This can lead to unexpected behavior if func has side-effects, as they
>   will take effect twice for the first column/row.

[Source](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html)